# Вызов методов при перезапуске приложения из Android Studio

Tags: android, android-fragment, activity

Прстите за дебильный вопрос, но какие методы вызываются у fragment, activity при перезапуске приложения из Android Studio???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос действительно так себе. Ответ по ссылке ниже.
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html#alc
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html?hl=ru#Creating